# How do I add vertical moving hover line to my plotly chart

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, onhover

I am trying to achieve what is done here: https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/120955 with javascript in python plotly. I want to add the hover vertical line and the red annotation on the x axis. I have done some searching on goolgle but I couldn't find the the answer I'm looking for. My current chart looks like this:

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(
x = df1.x,
y = df1.y,
name = "M&G OPTIMAL INCOME FD EUR AH ACC",
hoverinfo= 'name',
opacity=0.7,
mode = 'lines',
    line = dict(
    color = ('rgb(2, 12, 245)'),
    width = 1,
    ), 
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
x = df2.x,
y = df2.y,
opacity=0.7,
name = "Alloc Flexible Prudent Monde",
hoverinfo= 'name',
mode = 'lines',
    line = dict(
    color = ('rgb(67, 45, 24)'),
    width = 1,
    )
)
trace3 = go.Scatter(
x = df3.x,
y = df3.y,
name = "25% MSCI World + 75% ML Global",
hoverinfo= 'name',
mode = 'lines',
opacity=0.7,
line = dict(
    color = ('rgb(205, 12, 24)'),
    width = 1,
    )
)

layout = go.Layout(

xaxis=dict(        
    showline=True,
    showgrid=True,
    showticklabels=True,
    linecolor='rgb(204, 204, 204)',
    linewidth=2,
    mirror=True,
),
yaxis=dict(
            showline=True,
    showgrid=True,
    showticklabels=True,
    linecolor='rgb(204, 204, 204)',
    linewidth=2,
    mirror=True,
),
showlegend=True,

)

data= [trace1, trace2,trace3]
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename='line-mode')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your layout definition.

```
showlegend = True,
hovermode  = 'x'
```

Add this to your xaxis definition.

```
showspikes = True,
spikemode  = 'across',
spikesnap = 'cursor',
showline=True,
showgrid=True,
...
```

And add this to your layout definition:

```
spikedistance =  -1,
xaxis=dict(...
```

Please refer to this [post](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2155) and the documentation by [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-spikemode). :)

**EDIT**

You ask for the x-axis lable. Please use

```
spikemode  = 'across+toaxis'
```

Additionally I would suggest to use

```
spikedash = 'solid'
```

because it is better fitting your example.

Comment: I know it is not the perfect copy of your source, but it is already very close. Maybe you experiment a bit on your own. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding spikedash = 'solid' as well

Comment: Wonderful, glad that I could help!

Comment: Do you know how I could add the red annotation on the x axis as well?

Comment: What do you mean specifically?

Comment: https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/120955 If you check the link, you will see the red annotation of date moving with the vertical line.

Comment: Ah okay I see, I will get back to that by tomorrow. I will try to find you an answer!

Comment: I added the requested changes. Please elaborate, if it is fulfilling your needs. :))